# Why do I get the wrong address for a variable in gdb when using p &var?

Tags: c, gdb

I have a simple c program:

```
int x = 0;

void main() {
        int y = 1;
        printf("x: %d\n", x);
        printf("y: %d\n", y);
        printf("&x: %p\n", (void*) &x);
        printf("&y: %p\n", (void*) &y);
}
```

which I have compiled with `gcc -g simple.c`

Now I run `./simple` and get:

```
&x: 0x557123835014
&y: 0x7ffcad2a35f4
```

But when I try to retrieve the address with gdb, I get a different result. My steps:

```
gdb ./simple

(gdb) b main

(gdb) run

(gdb) step
(gdb) step

(gdb) p &x
$4 = (int *) 0x555555558014 <x>
(gdb) p&y
$5 = (int *) 0x7fffffffde14
```

The values seem to be not very far away from each other, but why don't I get the same result?
Let me know if you need additional information and thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Do you get the same addresses the next time you run the program?

Comment: The program is loaded at a different address each time you load it. Nothing to worry about :)

Comment: oh, thank you very much ;D ;D Now I understand it

Comment: What addresses were printed when the code fully executed in the debugger? Betting that the output would replicate what the debugger showed.

Comment: Surely there's some canonical dupe for ASLR... anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some operating systems randomizes addresses as a security measure.  On Linux, for instance, that features is called [Address Space Layout Randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) (ASLR) and enabled by default.

By default GDB will disable address space randomization, so the addresses you see when running under GDB should be consistent.  Use `show disable-randomization` to see if randomization has been disabled or not.

You can always use `set disable-randomization off` to turn off the disabling, which will then leave randomization on (if the OS has it on by default), but that's very rarely helpful when debugging.